# Mysqldump - typed mysql instead

Tags: mysql, mysql-backup

I was trying to backup a MySQL database via command line and I typed

```
mysql -u -root -p -h server.com DATABASE > file.sql
```

INSTEAD OF

```
mysqldump -u -root -p -h server.com DATABASE > file.sql
```

It created a file on my desktop so I thought it was working and I left it for about an hour.

I then realized that it still wasn't finished, pressed ctrl + c to kill it.

I then opened file.sql and there was nothing in it.

What just happened? Did I just corrupt my database?

Comment: you redirected `mysql -u -root -p -h server.com DATABASE` command's output to `file.sql`. which is nothing. yu didn't corrupt your database. try accessing your database.

Comment: Cool. That's what I was hoping. I did some 'SELECT count(*)' and it seemed to be okay, just wanted to double check with people who know for sure.